# allow URI change in code igniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, hyperlink

I'm fairly new to code igniter, and All of my links have the this path "/folder/file". So I expect that when I call the link, it should show:

```
www.website.com/folder/file
```

but when I click it instead it goes to this:

```
www.website.com/index.php/folder/file
```

How do I prevent it from happening? I want it to be relative as well.

Do I need to touch something in the configs?

Comment: do you want to remove index.php from url?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove index.php from url, just follow below steps:

1) Create .htacess file in parallel to application holder
 and just copy past the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /CodeIgniter/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

2) Change $config['index_page'] to blank in config.php in application folder as below:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

3) Enable "rewrite_module" of apache.

My Detail blog:http://change-in-codeigniter.blogspot.in/

Comment: `RewriteBase /CodeIgniter/` Which Version?

Answer (score 0):

If in case u r using IIS you need to create a file called web.config in the root directory and paste the following

```
<system.webServer>

    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>

    <rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="RuleRemoveIndex" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true"/>
        </rule>
    </rules>
    </rewrite>

</system.webServer>

<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check This

On config.php

```
 $config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

On .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```